# compile software with older version of gcc and linux kernel

Tags: linux, opensuse, sles, linux-kernel, gcc

```
Distributor ID: SUSE LINUX
Description:    openSUSE 11.4 (x86_64)
Release:    11.4
Codename:   Celadon

gcc (SUSE Linux) 4.5.1

Linux linux-14ay 2.6.37.6-0.20-desktop #1 SMP PREEMPT 2011-12-19 23:39:38 +0100 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I am trying to install software on the above system. However, the software that I need requires an earlier version of gcc (version 4.1) my current install version is 4.5.1. It is possible to install an 4.1 on my current system? Where would I get the gcc version from?

Also, I get this message about the Linux kernel

```
The current kernel version (2.6.37.6-0.20-desktop) is later than
the version currently supported by this software (2.6.5)
```

Is it possible to install this earlier kernel. Where would I get that from?

Comment: What software is this?

Comment: @Michael, Software in Dialogic PowerMedia HMP 4.1.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you set up a chroot environment with the "alternative" distribution and you can compile using an older version of gcc and related libraries / binaries.

I have used schroot on ubuntu to massively ease the pain in the process.

http://masterpatricko.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/development-and-build-environments_20.html

details how you can use schroot with Suse.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good idea to run unsupported packages unless you know want you are doing, and since you are coming here for help, you probably should abide by this warning. Looking at the [Release Guide](http://www.dialogic.com/Manuals/hmp/hmp41lin.aspx) for your software, RedHat 5u6 is the latest supported distribution, so why don't you install that (you can probably get away with CentOS 5.6) in a virtual machine and avoid all headache.

Answer (score 0):

If you can install an older distro, yoou may be able to make a static linked binary with a tool like this:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/statifier/
which I would hope would work on the more modern system.

Alternatively run a VM of the older distro?